# Nonlinear First-Order ODE: $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1}{x\cos(y)+y\sin(2y)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Having some fun with this:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1}{x\cos(y)+y\sin(2y)}
$$
I have tried various substitutions and factorizations, and an obvious trig identity. It looks like a numerical problem to me. I would appreciate any hints/ideas to find a function $f(x,y)=C$ with this property.

Comment: I think you are right - numerical methods is the way to go on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is as close as you can get: If you view $x$ as a function of $y$, your differential equation will be
$$
x'-x\cos y=y\sin2y,
$$
which you might be able to solve using integrating factor. You will end up with something like
$$
xe^{-\sin y}=\int y e^{-\sin y}\sin(2y)\,dy.
$$
It seems difficult to find a closed expression for that integral, though.